When implementing Algorithm X, how do I iterate until all possible solutions are created and shown?
I'm trying to use Algorithm X to solve the exact cover problem of a given matrix. Details of Algorithm X I'm meant to implement:

First we find a column c with the fewest 1s, pick row r that contains a 1 in column c, add row r to L, eliminate rows that collide with row r, eliminate columns that collide with row r, remove row r, output the remaining matrix.
I've hardcoded a matrix to make testing easier. Upon debugging, my functions work individually, but my logic is off. It can only output one answer instead of every solution, and it's saving the incorrect rows when it iterates through the matrix. One of the solutions for the given matrix is L = {2, 4, 6}, but I'm only getting {0, 4, 2}.
def check_zeros(matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix[0])):  # iterate through each column, size of row denotes each column index
        if all(matrix[j][i] == 0 for j in range(len(matrix))):  # if all entries in a column are 0
            return True  # indicates no solution for this matrix
    return False

def check_ones(matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):  # iterate through each row
        if all(matrix[i]):  # if the entire row consists of 1s
            return i  # return the index of the row
    return False  # returns false if none of the rows contain only 1's

def pick_columns(matrix): #saves the index of columns with 1's in ascending
    columns_with_ones = []

    for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
        num_ones = sum(matrix[i][j] for i in range(len(matrix)))
        if num_ones > 0:
            columns_with_ones.append((j, num_ones)) 
    
    columns_with_ones.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    sorted_columns = [col[0] for col in columns_with_ones]
    return sorted_columns


def pick_rows(matrix, column):
    return [i for i in range(len(matrix)) if matrix[i][column] == 1]

def remove_column(matrix, column):
    return [[row[j] for j in range(len(row)) if j != column] for row in matrix]

def remove_rows(matrix, row):
    new_matrix = []
    for i, r in enumerate(matrix):
        if i == row:
            continue  # skip the selected row
        # Append rows that do not conflict with the selected row
        if not any(matrix[row][j] == 1 and r[j] == 1 for j in range(len(matrix[0]))):
            new_matrix.append(r)
    return new_matrix

def remove_columns(matrix, row):
    columns_to_remove = [j for j in range(len(matrix[0])) if matrix[row][j] == 1]
    new_matrix = [list(r) for r in matrix] #create a copy to avoid modifying the original
    for col in reversed(columns_to_remove):
        new_matrix = remove_column(new_matrix, col)
    return new_matrix

def exact_cover_problem():
    arr = []
    col = 0

    while True:
        inp = input("Input matrix by each row, press 'y' to stop (example 1010): \n")
        if inp.lower() != "y":
            arr.append(inp)
            col = max(col, len(inp))
        else:
            break

    matrix = [list(map(int, s.ljust(col, '0'))) for s in arr]
    print("\nExact Cover Problem:")
    for row in matrix:
        print(row)

    return matrix

def algorithm_x(matrix, L=None):
    if L is None:
        L = []

    # Check for columns without 1's
    if check_zeros(matrix):
        return None  # No solution

    # Check if there's a row with all 1's
    if (row := check_ones(matrix)) is not False:
        return L + [row]

    columns = pick_columns(matrix)
    if not columns:  # If no valid column found, return None
        return None
    
    column = columns[0]
    
    rows = pick_rows(matrix, column)

    for row in rows:
        new_matrix = remove_rows(matrix, row)
        new_matrix = remove_columns(new_matrix, row)

        result = algorithm_x(new_matrix, L + [row])
        if result:
            return result

    return None

# Main execution
matrix = [
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
]
result = algorithm_x(matrix)

# Display the results
# print("\nSolutions using Knuth's Algorithm X:")
# if result:
#     print("Rows selected (L):", result)
# else:
#     print("No exact cover solution found :(")

print("\nAll possible solutions using Knuth's Algorithm X:")
if result:
    print(f"Solution: {result}")
else:
    print("No exact cover solution found :(")


Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you single-stepped your code in the debugger to see where it fails? If you don't yet know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn. It's one of the most powerful tools at your disposal. In any case, what else have you done in an attempt to find the bug?
